# Passing base64 encrypted string in the URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc, base64, url-encoding

I would like to know if I can pass a base64 encrypted , encoded string in the URL. Could you please advice on this !

Ex : https://localhost:1234/sampleapp/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=/abcded.pdf

When I wrote this in Spring , below is the controller I wrote :

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/sampleapp")
 public class ABC {

      @RequestMapping("/{encryptedText}/{fileName}")
      public bye[] streamContent(@PathVariable String encryptedText, @PathVariable String fileName){

      return ;
     }

 }
```

Comment: Or Even Best Way of doing this is also good..

Comment: Have you tired this ?

Comment: I have a simple util for encrypt/decrypt - https://gist.github.com/zhong-j-yu/9d23c850e580d60ddd46

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, as long as as the base64 string is URL Safe, this is replacing the non safe characters: `'+', '/'` and removing the padding character `=` of the Base64 string.

I'd recommend you this apache [Apache commons-codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) library that you can use to encode/decode [Base64 URL Strings](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafe(byte[])).

Hope this helps,

Jose Luis